# passing data between activities

Tags: java, android

I want to send a treemap between two activities,how can i do this?

Comment: There is probably a better way but you could write some functionality to serialize the data into a format supported by bundles and stick that information in the `Bundle` sent with the `Intent`. A quick search showed `TreeMap` as not being serializable by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this page, hopefully that will point you in the right direction. Then when you chose your method, you can ask more specific questions
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3